# "winmm.dll" won't play certain wav sounds?

Tags: delphi, winapi, audio

Apparently, Windows made some major changes to the audio architecture in Windows Vista. 
As I understand it, some "legacy codecs" are not included in Vista and above, but I'm not sure whether this is the cause of the problem.

I am programming in Delphi, and am currently using `C:\WINDOWS\System32\winmm.dll` from the Windows library and its [PlaySound method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/the-playsound-function) to play Waveform Audio File Format (WAV) files. 
It seems like there are a number of WAV files that `winmm.dll` cannot play. 
Interestingly, Windows Media Player can play the failing sounds, while the Windows Control Panel sound applet cannot. Therefore, I suspect that the failure to play the sounds may be due to a limitation of the library I am using, and is not directly caused by my app. 
Still, it causes a bad user experience to have sound files silently fail without any notice to the user that the file is somehow defective and cannot be used.

Is there a different library function I should be using instead to play the WAV sounds with better codec support, which would be able to play these broken files like Windows Media Player can? 
If not, is there another function call I could use to test whether a WAV is valid/playable, so I can notify the user that the file's internal format isn't supported?

Comment: Have you tried opening these Wav files in Audacity and finding out what CODEC they use?

Comment: Can you give me any pointers about how to identify the CODEC through Audacity? I was able to convert one of the defective files (a sound file from an old version of AOL instant messenger) to a WAV file that will play in windows and my app. But I'm not sure how to identify the codec

Comment: unless "32-bit float" is the encoding. However, another sound clip from the same set has the same value and it plays fine.

Comment: I see Mono or Stereo, sample rate (hz) and resolution (16,24,32 bit) yes.  If there was some other weird encoding details it is possible they aren't visible in Audacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window Media Player uses DirectShow which gives you better performance and greater flexibility than PlaySound under MCI. However, it can seem like a lot of effort to play a sound with DirectShow compared to MCI.

Have a look at the [cbAudioPlay](http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=41) component by Carlos Barbosa, as it provides a good example of using DirectShow and contains the associated libs you need.